# Nginx HTTPS redirect for angular i18n application

Tags: angular, nginx, http-redirect

I configured angular localization and used the NGINX example that they provided in the documentation. Everything works fine, however I have an issue with redirection. My domain is using https, so if the user hits https://www.example.com, nginx redirects to http://www.example.com/en

So, redirects to the correct language location but using HTTP instead.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /www/data;

    # Fallback to default language if no preference defined by browser
    if ($accept_language ~ "^$") {
        set $accept_language "fr";
    }

    # Redirect "/" to Angular app in browser's preferred language
    rewrite ^/$ /$accept_language permanent;

    # Everything under the Angular app is always redirected to Angular in the correct language
    location ~ ^/(fr|de|en) {
        try_files $uri /$1/index.html?$args;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to specify that it should redirect to HTTPS in the code below?

```
    # Everything under the Angular app is always redirected to Angular in the correct language
    location ~ ^/(fr|de|en) {
        try_files $uri /$1/index.html?$args;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone has the same issue, I fixed by using

```
absolute_redirect off;
```

It will force the Location header to use a relative URL.

```
Location: /en
```